# call openlayers function with jquery

Tags: jquery, set, visibility, openlayers

I am trying to get OpenLayers to set visibility for a Layer whe users selects input element using jQuery.

Here is  a part of code where are layers defined:

```js
stars = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("stars", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "textfile.txt",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.Text()
    })
});

home = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("home", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "textfile1.txt",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.Text()
    })
});
map.addLayers([stars, home]);
```

Hers is part of html code:

```
 <ul>
    <li class="ls_sivi"> <input type="checkbox" value="1" style="width:auto"><label>stars</label></li>
    <li class="ls_sivi"><input type="checkbox" value="2" style="width:auto"><label>home</label></li>
 </ul>`
```

And than jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var sloj = new Array();
 sloj[1]=stars;
 sloj[2]=home;

 $('.ls_sivi input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var vri = $(this).val();  

    if($(this).is(":checked")){ 
       sloj[vri].setVisibility(true);  
       return
      }
       sloj[vri].setVisibility(false);
     });
  });
```

I get:

> "sloj[vri].setVisibility" is not a function.

How could I solve this problem because I have more layers and this would be the easiest way?

Comment: I think you should double-check your checkbox referencing. I think the reason it's saying that's not a function is because vri isn't what you think it is.

Comment: you are right, but replacing vri with the number I get; Cannot convert 'sloj[2]' to object

Comment: I posted the answer so you can accept it and move this from being unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
map.getLayer(sloj[vri].id).setVisibility();
```